# AppDelegate type var is not member unless in func (see pictures)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, member, appdelegate

I'm just starting Swift, have some Objective-C background... Anyways, why is it that when I do:
[image: error]

I get an error, but when I put it in a func like:

[image: good]

There isn't an error?

Also, can someone please correct my terms? is appDel a reference or a variable? Thanks in advanced - please edit or tell me what's wrong with my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access `self` when setting the default value.

Mark it with `lazy` attribute can do the trick:

```
lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = self.appDel.managedObjectContext
```

Comment: wow thank! so does `lazy` only initiate it when it's needed? and why do I need to use self? isn't appDel already declared?

Comment: Yes it is not calculated until the first time it is used. `lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = self.appDel.managedObjectContext` implies `lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext =  { return self.appDel.managedObjectContext }()` and Swift requires we to use `self` explicitly in closure.